# Разбор по членам предложения

Tags: синтаксис, члены-предложения

**У меня мало времени.**

Не могу понять: чем является словосочетание *мало времени* в предложении?

Comment: Сущ. - это часть речи. Мало времени - подлежащее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня **нет** времени. У меня **не было** времени.

У меня **мало** времени. У меня **было мало** времени.

У меня **достаточно** времени. У меня **было достаточно** времени.

По поводу этих предложений с количественным значением **нет единого мнения**, но вот такое сопоставление позволяет отнести их к **безличным предложениям отрицательно-бытийного или количественно-бытийного плана**.

Семантический субъект выражен Р.п. Слова ***нет, мало, достаточно***  предикативы, то есть выступают в роли сказуемого.

Comment: А если так: У меня была уйма времени. Здесь тоже количественное значение. Здесь тоже безличное?

Comment: Безличная форма глаголов быть, стать с отрицанием: (Не было ни гроша, да вдруг алтын; Не было сил перенести это; Прошло несколько дней с тех пор, как его не стало).

Comment: У нас ведь нет отрицания.

Comment: Но я же говорю о двух значениях: отрицательно-бытийном и количественно- бытийном.  Не все количественные примеры подходят под эту тему (наличие и оценка  количества чего-либо)  и под грамматику безличного предложения. Не было сил (для чего?) перенести это (это безличное предложение).